# How to tell if something was REBASED when merged?

Tags: git, github

I have this script that cleans up local git branches after they've been merged over on GitHub.com. Under the hood it runs `git checkout master && git pull origin master && git branch --merged` to get a list of local branches that can be deleted now.

If I push a branch to GitHub and use the ["Confirm squash and merge"](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits) feature. When I run the same command as mentioned above (`git branch --merged`) these won't show up.

Comment: For cleanup purpose, I don't really do any rebase detection. Instead I have a special local branch `graveyard`, and a script which merges there all branch which has not been active for some time (something like 2 months is there).  Then I can remove that branches. This allows me to keep their number down without worrying that something is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Merge-squash adds changes from branch without actually marking it as merged. So you could try to look for identical changes. You can do it using `git patch-id` command. For a single branch B it should be something like:

```
branch_id=$(git diff origin/master...B | git patch-id)
git rev-list --max-parents=1 B..origin/master \
  | while read hash; do commit_id=$(git show "$hash" | git patch-id); if test "$commit_id" = "$branch_id"; then <do what you planned to do with the branch>; break; fi; done
```

If you have many branches you can consider to add some caching to avoid calculating patch-id for same commit many times.

Comment: On the first time, `branch_id` isn't an ID. It's a diff. On the next line you compare outputs of `..sometthing... | git patch-id` to a diff.

Comment: fixed it. sorry if mislead.

Comment: In general this fails because `git patch-id` includes the commit message (and possibly other metadata) so the hashes differ. I'm expressing myself poorly but I made this: https://gist.github.com/peterbe/152ad7f53184a0359dc237f02bd7bef3

Comment: In your example, there is "line4" in only one diff. I suspect (did not check it) that this is the reason why patch-ids are different. This is really an issue with this solution - if you apply patch to a different code - event when git can merge the changes automatically - patch-id can change. You could try getting patch with smaller context, like `-U1` for example, but in some cases if will still fail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can check from the github API that pullrequest is merged and consider the branch is merged too.

So, for example, if you want to know which branches from repository https://github.com/JetBrains/gitextensions were merged into https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions , you make request to https://api.github.com/repos/gitextensions/gitextensions/pulls?state=closed , then pick your merged branches with code like this (python2):

```
import curl
import json

c = curl.Curl()
content = c.get('https://api.github.com/repos/gitextensions/gitextensions/pulls?state=closed')

d = json.decoder.JSONDecoder()
c_parsed = d.decode(content)

for pr in c_parsed:
    if pr[u'head'][u'repo'] is not None and pr[u'head'][u'repo'][u'full_name'] == u"JetBrains/gitextensions":
        print pr[u'head'][u'ref']
```